# Having issues with my switch statement. Keeps going to the default value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Trying to get better at OOP. I can't seem to get this switch statement to work. It's console logging the right value(level) but the case in the switch statement is not recognizing. I keep get getting the default message.

```
function Haircut(adult, price, gratuity, gratuityAmount) {
    this.adult = adult;
    this.price = price;
    this.gratuity = gratuity;
    this.gratuityAmount = gratuityAmount;
}

Haircut.prototype.status = function () {
    const level = parseInt(this.gratuityAmount);
    console.log(level);
    switch (level) {
        case level >= 20:
            console.log("You are a Platinum Level Client!");
            break;
        case level >= 15:
            console.log("You are a Gold Level Client!");
            break;
        case level >= 10:
            console.log("You are a Silver Level Client!");
            break;
        case level >= 5:
            console.log("You are a Bronze Level Client!");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("You don't tip! That sucks!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's impossible to use greater than and less than directly in switch statement.
But in directly you can implement the above code like this :

```
switch (true) {
    case level >= 20:
        console.log("You are a Platinum Level Client!");
        break;
    case level >= 15:
        console.log("You are a Gold Level Client!");
        break;
    case level >= 10:
        console.log("You are a Silver Level Client!");
        break;
    case level >= 5:
        console.log("You are a Bronze Level Client!");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("You don't tip! That sucks!");
}
```

Meaning, please try to change `switch (level)` by `switch (true)` and then try again.
Anyway, I suggest to use `if, else if, else` statement rather than switch in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going w/the if/else statement